# What does "sudo chown -R hadoop:hadoop hadoop" do?

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

I saw the following script, posted online, that was used during the hadoop installation process.

```
  sudo tar xzf hadoop-0.20.2.tar.gz
  sudo mv hadoop-0.20.2 hadoop
  sudo chown -R hadoop:hadoop hadoop
```

I do not quite understand. What does the

```
    sudo chown -R hadoop:hadoop hadoop
```

do here? Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: it CHange OWNer of `hadoop` directory and everything under it (-R) to `hadoop:handoop` (user:group). see the `chown` manual: http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown

Comment: The syntax of linux commands is always listed in the man page. You can look up what any command and it's options by pulling up it's manual like this: `man chown`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command [`chown`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) changes the ownership of files or directories.

The `-R` flag makes the command recursive, ie. it is applied to all the files and sub-directories inside given directory.

The string `hadoop:hadoop` changes the ownership (`user:group`).

The final `hadoop` is the name of the directory whose ownership is going to be changed.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I would only add that changing file/directory ownership requires root permissions, therefore the chown command is run with sudo.